# Spring Boot Cors Filter returning Access-Control-Allow-Origin: null

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, cors

I have a small Spring boot App and stuck with this CORS Issue

Failed to load http://localhost:8093/trial/events/?_=1522319557789: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'null' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Have followed the Spring documentation and this is my config :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig  extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**");
}

}
```

I get a 200 response from Server but with Access-Control-Allow-Origin: null.

So Chrome is complaining with the above Error .

Tried setting the header manually in the Controller but now I could see 2 headers with the same Name .
And Chrome again complains for multiple headers with same Name.

Not sure where Spring configures the Access-Control-Allow-Origin as Null 
Any Help s appreciated.Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring boot properties prefixed by endpoints.cors.* are used by Actuator so that's why it will not work with MVC endpoints.

Try below snippet

```
    registry.addMapping("/trial/**")
        .allowedOrigins("http://localhost") // Add you arigins here ,to bypass all the origins you can put "*".
        .allowedMethods("PUT", "DELETE","POST","GET") // add allowed methods here
        .allowedHeaders("header1", "header2", "header3")// add allowed headers here
        .exposedHeaders("header1", "header2") // add exposed headers here
        .allowCredentials(false).maxAge(3600);
```

The default logic could be found in class *org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration.java*

```
/**
 * Set the origins to allow, e.g. {@code "http://domain1.com"}.
 * <p>The special value {@code "*"} allows all domains.
 * <p>By default this is not set.
 */
public void setAllowedOrigins(@Nullable List<String> allowedOrigins) {
    this.allowedOrigins = (allowedOrigins != null ? new ArrayList<>(allowedOrigins) : null);
}
```

By default this is not set.Hence you need to set it explicitly using

```
.allowedOrigins()
```

Comment: Thanks !
It gives a new error now :

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Thats my request : 
     $.ajax({
           url: endpointUrl,
            cache: false,
            context: data,
            success: function(){
                alert("Success");
              $(this).addClass("done");
            }
  
        });

Comment: It behaves a bit weird . I see the response body showing up randomly .But the error is consistent in every request .

Comment: Ok, finally it works . Your solution combined with manually setting the response header in the controller fixed the issue . Thanks a lot!

response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");